# Is it possible to start Self-Signed Docker Registry in Kubernetes and have other service use that as the registry to get its image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-registry, kubelet

### Problem Statement

- I want to deliver a private registry which all the images I need for my product bundled in them ( Yes, It will be fat image, but I am fine with that)
- I would manually upload this image in some way
- I would run the docker private registry as a service in Kubernetes (probably in some namespace)
- When other services/deployments (in the same namespace as registry)  happen in Kubernetes, they should refer to this registry using a consistent name

### Constraints

- We want registry to be exposed only to the cluster and not outside
- We want to use self signed certificate and not signed by CA

I followed some instructions from these links (do not know whether it was a right thing to do)

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#create-a-certificate-signing-request-object-to-send-to-the-kubernetes-api

#### Create a certificate signed through Kubernetes

1. Create a server.key
2. Create a csr.info

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C = US
ST = oh
L = cincinnati
O = engg
OU = prod
CN = prateek.svc.cluster.local

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local

[ v3_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage=keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=@alt_names
```

3. Created the server.csr (openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config csr.conf)
4. Create the CertificateSigningRequest in K8s

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
name: registry.prateek
spec:
groups:
- system:authenticated
request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
usages:
- digital signature
- key encipherment
- server auth
EOF
```

5. Checked if the CSR exists

```
kubectl describe csr registry.prateek
Name: registry.prateek
Labels: <none>
Annotations: kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"CertificateSigningRequest","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"registry.prateek","namespace":""},"spec":{"groups":["system:authenticated"],"request":"LS0sdfsfsdsfd=","usages":["digital signature","key encipherment","server auth"]}}

CreationTimestamp: Thu, 11 Apr 2019 11:15:42 -0400
Requesting User: docker-for-desktop
Status: Pending
Subject:
Common Name: prateek.svc.cluster.local
Serial Number:
Organization: engg
Organizational Unit: prod
Country: US
Locality: cincinnati
Province: oh
Subject Alternative Names:
DNS Names: registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local
Events: <none>
```

6. Approved the CSR : kubectl certificate approve registry.prateek

#### Start the registry internal service

7. Added cert and key to the kind: Secret

registry-secret.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registry-credentials
data:
  certificate: <CERTIFICATE in base64>
  key: <KEY in base64>
```

8. Create registry deployment and service (using those secrets)

   registry-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: registry
  namespace: prateek
  labels:
      app: registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: registry
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: registry
          image: prateek/registry
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
          env:
            - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR
              value: "0.0.0.0:443"
            - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
              value: "/certs/certificate"
            - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
              value: "/certs/key"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cert-files
              mountPath: /certs
      volumes:
        - name: cert-files
          secret:
            secretName: registry-credentials
```

#### registry-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: registry
  namespace: prateek
spec:
  selector:
    app: registry
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  type: LoadBalancer
```

#### Test regsitry service is up

9. Tried to this the registry endpoint thru a test pod. I had image of this test pod loaded in docker already.

```
curl https://registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/v2/_catalog -k
{"repositories":["prateek/echo"]}
```

#### Deployment using image from the registry service

10. Tried deployment with image: registry.prateek/prateek/echo:latest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: cequence
  labels:
      app: hello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: registry.prateek/prateek/echo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
         - containerPort: 5678
        args: ["-text=hello"]
```

11. the deployment gives the error

```
Normal Pulling 10s (x2 over 25s) kubelet, docker-for-desktop pulling image "registry.prateek/prateek/echo:latest"
Warning Failed 10s (x2 over 25s) kubelet, docker-for-desktop Failed to pull image "registry.prateek/prateek/echo:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.prateek/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

12. Changed deployment to have image: registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/prateek/echo:latest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: cequence
  labels:
      app: hello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/prateek/echo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
         - containerPort: 5678
        args: ["-text=hello"]
```

13. get the similar error

```
Warning Failed 1s kubelet, docker-for-desktop Failed to pull image "registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/prateek/echo:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

I do not that this is even possible. Run a docker registry as a service and point other service in the namespace to use that registry deployment in the cluster. Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: You wrong from this step: `image: registry.prateek/prateek/echo:latest`. `registry.prateek` should be your domain name. Example: `my-registry.com/slack-assistant-service:0.1.6-2`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn, I tried even this image name: registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/prateek/echo:latest.

This is supposed to use the service name of the registry within the cluster.

Also, I do not want to expose an registry in my domain. The private registry within the cluster

Comment: You must able to access `registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local` from your Pod, let try to `kubectl exec ...` into a container running and telnet to `registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local` port 443

Comment: Yes, I was able to run a test pod and then do curl
curl https://registry.prateek.svc.cluster.local/v2/_catalog -k
{"repositories":["prateek/echo"]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container daemon is running outside of kubernetes.

Therefore, if you want to pull the image, you need to make sure that the registry is reachable from the node directly, without using kubernetes mechanisms like a service. (Not like you tested it in step 9 through a pod, you must be able to work directly on the node!)

The usual options are to create a DNS entry or hosts.txt entry to point to a node where either through a `hostPort` (container) or `nodePort` (service) the registry is accessible or you use an appropriate ingress.

Comment: What you are saying is that it is not really possible to have an internal-to-cluster-registry-service as docker registry for other services in the cluster.

The only way possible is to have registry service exposed through one of the node's port and map that node to a resolvable name on other nodes.

Comment: The registry is used by the container engine on the host, not by other services in the kubernetes cluster. Therefore it must be accessible from the node, either using mapped ports directly or using Ingress or LoadBalancer services.